# Subadditivity of total variation of signed measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to understand the proof of subadditivity for the total variation of a signed measure but I can't understand a step of the proof.

Let $E=\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} E_j$. We want to show that $|\nu |(E)\leq\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |\nu| (E_j) $. Let $\{F_j\}$ a partition of $E$. Then $$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|\nu (F_j)| \leq \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|\nu(E_{j,k})| \leq \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |\nu|(E_j)$$ where $E_{j,k}=F_k\cap E_j$. And since $\{F_j\}$ is a arbitrary partition we are basically done.

The part that I can't understand is the first inequality $$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|\nu (F_j)| \leq \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|\nu(E_{j,k})|$$ I think there is an application of the triangle inequality involved, but the fact that the $E_i$'s are not disjoint make it hard for me to figure it out. Could anyone help me understand this step? Is there any other inequality / equality for signed measures involved there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the claimed inequality 
$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|\nu (F_j)| \leq \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|\nu(E_{j,k})|$$
is false. A simple counterexample is the measure $\nu=\delta_1+\delta_2-\delta_0$ on $\mathbb{R}$ with $E=\{0,1,2\}$, $E_1=\{0,1\}$, $E_2=\{0,2\}$, and $F_1=E$. Then $\nu(F_1)=1$ but $\nu(E_{1,k})=0$ for $k=1,2$.

To fix the proof, introduce the sets 
$$E_1'=E_1,\ E_2'=E_2\setminus E_1,\ E_3'=E_3\setminus (E_1\cup E_2), \dots$$
Then the proof works for $E_j'$ (which are disjoint) and so
$$
|\nu|(E)\le \sum_j |\nu|(E_j')\le  \sum_j |\nu|(E_j)
$$
because $E_j'\subset E_j$ and $|\nu|$ is monotone with respect to containment.